# NSRegularExpression Help, parse list of names in natural syntax (Bob, Julie, and Bill)

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I've searched all over the Internet and have tried countless combinations for a long time and still can't come up with a correct regex.

Here is what I want to achieve

Input:

> "Henry Smith, Bill Low, and April Kamko"

Capture:

> ["Henry Smith", "Bill Low", "April Kamko"]

Input: (notice the lack of comma before "and")

> "Steve Jobs and Steve Woz"

Capture:

> ["Steve Jobs", "Steve Woz"]

The most logical one I can come up with is
`(?:([^,]+), )+and ([^,]+)`
But this one only gives me the last two names out of three. Furthermore, I can't seem to find what happens when you put a capturing-group inside a non-capturing group.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered using `NSScanner`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pretty easy approach:

```
NSString *input = @"Henry Smith, Bill Low, and April Kamko";
input = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\s*(?:(?:and|,)\\s*)+"
                                         withString:@","
                                            options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                              range:(NSRange){0, [input length]}];

NSLog(@"names: %@", [input componentsSeparatedByString:@","]);
```

The idea is to first normalize and merge all occurrences of separators `"and"` and `"'"` to a single separator `","` (eating up optional whitespace while we're at it).

Then just split the string at `","`.

When your input strings are less strictly defined you might want to look into [`NSLinguisticTagger`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSLinguisticTagger_Class/Reference/Reference.html), especially with options like `NSLinguisticTagSchemeNameType`, `NSLinguisticTagPersonalName`, and `NSLinguisticTaggerJoinNames`.

Comment: Thank you so much! NSLinguisticTagger is an interesting discovery, but I think I'll stick to your method for now since the sentences are regular and generated by another software.